# look and feel of stacked tab is different on version is < 3.0 and different on version is >3.0

Tags: android

I have created actionBar from actionBar Style Generator and copy paste the style in my apps.I created UI for stacked tab using tabwidget .
but when I use this actionbar style in my manifest file like android:theme="@style/Theme.Customtheme" that look and feel not same as the actionbar(on version 4.2), that I was Created on Action Bar Style Generator. Second is When I run my application on Android 2.3.3 then it show different look and feel to android 4.2.  I want same look and feel on all version and I am using sherlock library for support all version. I Goggled lot but not get perfect solution.please anybody suggest the answer.
thanks in advance.

following is my code Sherlockfragment

```
public class CustomActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
TabHost tHost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom);

        tHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tHost.setup();

        /** Defining Tab Change Listener event. This is invoked when tab is changed */
        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener tabChangeListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                FragmentManager fm =   getSupportFragmentManager();
                ResidentialFragment resdentialFragment = (ResidentialFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("residential");
                CommercialFragment commercialFragment = (CommercialFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("commercial");
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                if (resdentialFragment!=null) {
                    ft.detach(resdentialFragment);
                }       
                /** Detaches the commercialfragment if exists */
                if (commercialFragment!=null) {
                    ft.detach(commercialFragment);
                }
                /** If current tab is residential */
                if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("residential")){

                    if(resdentialFragment==null){
                        /** Create residentialFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new ResidentialFragment(), "residential");
                    }else{
                        /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.attach(resdentialFragment);
                    }

                }else{    /** If current tab is apple */
                    if(commercialFragment==null){
                        /** Create AppleFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new CommercialFragment(), "commercial");
                     }else{
                        /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.attach(commercialFragment);
                    }
                }
                ft.commit();
            }
        };

        /** Setting tabchangelistener for the tab */
        tHost.setOnTabChangedListener(tabChangeListener);

        /** Defining tab builder for residential tab */
        TabHost.TabSpec tSpecResidential = tHost.newTabSpec("residential");
        tSpecResidential.setIndicator("Residential");
        tSpecResidential.setContent(new DummyTabContent(getBaseContext()));
        tHost.addTab(tSpecResidential);

        /** Defining tab builder for commercial tab */
        TabHost.TabSpec tSpecComm = tHost.newTabSpec("commercial");
        tSpecComm.setIndicator("Commercial");
        tSpecComm.setContent(new DummyTabContent(getBaseContext()));
        tHost.addTab(tSpecComm);

    }
}
```

following is my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.customactivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customactivity.CustomActivity"
            android:label="@string/projects"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Customtheme" 
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customactivity.ResidentialFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_residential" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.customactivity.CommercialFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_commercial" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here I am attaching Look and feel which I want.

[image]

following image from version 4.2

[image]

following image from version 2.3.3

[image]

Comment: is your minimum sdk version and target sdk version same?

Comment: no, this is android:minSdkVersion="4" and android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Comment: do both same as min sdk version and check

Comment: It is really hard to say what your problem is without some code. And secondly, you don't need a TabWidget if you want to add tabs to ActionBar. They should be added with `actionBar.newTab()` command. Also, ActionBar is not available on Android 2.3.3, so if you want to have a same look & feel as on version 4, you need to use ActionBarSherlock - http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: StinePike,you mean to say if minsdkversion is 4 then targersdkversion sholud be same but what version I should set so that it running on all version.

Comment: Dear lomza:yes I am using ActionBarSherlock library in my apps but with TabHost not actionBar.newTab().

Answer (score 0):

First of all to style an `ActionBar` using `ActionBarSherlock` you need to create the same style for every version of android (almost).
For example you need to create `styles.xml` and `theme.xml` in these folders of your app

```
- res
 -- values
   -- styles.xml
   --themes.xml
 -- values-11
   -- styles.xml
   -- themes.xml
 -- values-14
   -- styles.xml
   -- themes.xml
```

in these folders / files you will need to use different type of indicators. In default values folder you will have to use `Theme.Sherlock` (don't sure about the name) as parent or your custom theme, and you will need to style it using it's indicators like `actionbarStyle:`, without `android:` in front of it. I `values-14` for example you will use `Theme.Holo` as your parent theme of your custom one and there you will have to style your actionbar using `android:actionbarStyle` (as I remember the name of the value).

So if you want to style your action bar to look the same in all versions, you should take care of these styles in different versions.